# How to determine ResourceTag namespace (ec2:ResourceTag vs aws:ResourceTag vs iam:ResourceTag)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have recently been writing IAM policies using resource tags, below is an example.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/team": "${aws:PrincipalTag/team}",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/environment": "${aws:PrincipalTag/environment}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this doesn't allow the passing of roles (even if they are tagged) because that is `iam:ResourceTag` not `aws:ResourceTag`. How can I determine if a service uses `ec2:ResourceTags`, `aws:ResourceTags` or `iam:ResourceTags`

For example, I was tagging a Cloudformation stack and couldn't figure out if this tag type was `ec2:ResourceTag` or `aws:ResourceTag`. I discovered it was `aws:ResourceTag` through trial and error.

Additionally, is there a way to include all of these tags in my IAM policy (like `*:ResourceTags`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[aws:ResourceTag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-resourcetag) belongs to AWS **global condition** context keys (`aws` prefix). To check which services support this key, you can inspect `Authorization based on tags` in [AWS services that work with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) for service of interest.

[iam:ResourceTag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#ck_ResourceTag) or [ec2:ResourceTag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/control-access-with-tags.html) are **service specific condition** keys, in this case `iam` and `ec2` respectively. You can check all supported keys of each service in [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html).